# jZebra - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, javascript, applet

I've been successfully using jZebra in my development environment but now that I have moved it to the test environment, I get the following java console error when loading the html page that contains the applet:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jzebra.PrintApplet.class
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The HTML code is as follows:

```
        <div id="divAppletContainer" style="height:1px;width:1px;float:right;">
           <applet name="jZebra" id="jZebra" code="jzebra.PrintApplet.class" archive="/applets/jzebra/jzebra.jar" width="1" height="1">
              <param name="printer" value="epson">
              <!-- <param name="sleep" value="200"> -->
           </applet>
       </div>
```

Any ideas on why it is working in on instance and not another?

Comment: Is the absoluto path correct on the test environment?

Comment: Try loading the HTML with [Appleteer](http://pscode.org/appleteer/).  It will be more informative of any problems encountered.

Comment: Thanks guys, the problem was with security on the deployment folder on the second server